# facial expressions classification (emotions) in real time

Tags: opencv, expression, webcam, face-detection, feature-extraction

I am currently working on a project where I have to extract the facial expression of a user (only one user at a time from a webcam) like sad or happy.

The best possibility I found so far:

I used OpenCV for face detection.

Some user on a OpenCV board suggested looking for AAM (active apereance models) and ASM (active shape models), but all I found were papers.

-So i'm Using Active Shape Models with Stasm, which will give me access to 77 different points within the face like on the picture

[image]

now i want to know the best way to do :

- the best learning method to use on cohn and kanade database  to classify the emotions (happy,....) ?
- the best method to classify the facial expressions on a video in real time ?

Answer (score 1):

Look here for similar solution video and description of algorithm: http://www2.isr.uc.pt/~pedromartins/ in "Identity and Expression Recognition on Low Dimensional Manifolds" 2009 year.